# mvc3 load dynamic properties into javascript using razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var plug = new $.myPlugin({
    icon: "@ConfigurationManager.ApplicationIcon"
});
</script>
```

ConfigurationManager.ApplicationIcon - this method is returning a a path (string)
this is firing a compilation error - can you please help?

> *Compilation Error  Description: An error occurred during the compilation
>   of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following
>   specific error details and modify your
>   source code appropriately.  Compiler
>   Error Message: CS1502: The best
>   overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'
>   has some invalid arguments*

Comment: Where does `ConfigurationManager.ApplicationIcon` come from? Which is this class? Is it some custom built?

Answer (score 0):

missing () - sry guys - im still new to mvc 3

var plug = new $.myPlugin({
icon: "@ConfigurationManager.ApplicationIcon()"
});

Comment: Just edit your question if you have more information to add or want to make changes.